# Get each line from textarea that gets pushed to new line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, textarea

So I have a bunch of `textarea`'s ranging for 2-5 rows each. I am trying to separate each row into an array. Now normally we can do this by:

`$array = explode("\n", $textarea);`

But, what if you have a string that goes into a `textarea` that just get's pushed to a new line because there is no more space for it to be on that line?

Could anyone helping me figure out how to split it up then?

[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7JBe/2/) does exactly what I need in javascript except in php

Comment: what are you using the textarea for? sounds like you shouldn't, at all if this is an issue

Comment: Sending data to a PDF fillable form. Text needs to be within lines on a page so I separate it by line

Comment: text input fields instead of a textarea then

Comment: I can't because the inputting of the text need to work like `textarea` when writing from lines to lines not like an `input`. When I type it needs to move form line to line. When I delete in a random spot, it needs to be pushed back to previous lines, etc. Are you basically saying my question cannot be done?

Comment: well the question is still a little hazy to me, but it does sound unachievable.

Comment: [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7JBe/2/) does exactly what I need in javascript except in php

Comment: you have to do this in javascript, unless PDF library can set limits. Just send resultant array to php with ajax. Curious why can't set width of form element in PDF same as textarea on page...nullifying need to do this

Comment: @charlietfl I have to use individual text boxes in PDF because you can't set line height in PDF

Comment: OK...so have to use javascript then to get data...you already posted a solution, use that one